# how to make videothumbnail from the middle of the video?

Tags: html, node.js, video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg as my module in Node js app for making video thumbnails.the thing is , it makes it from the beginning of the Video. and some of them begins with a black frame so the thumbnail will be a black picture.I want to know how should I make it from the middle of the video so that they wont be black anymore.
here is what I did:

```
module.exports.createVideoThumbnail = function (path, destination, fileName, cb) 
{
    try 
    {
        var process = new ffmpeg(path);
        process.then(function (video) {
            video.fnExtractFrameToJPG(destination, {
                frame_rate: 1,
                number: 1,
                start_time: 20,
                duration_time: 1,
                file_name: `${fileName}`
            }, function (error, files) {
                if (!error) 
                {
                    console.log('Frames: ');
                    cb(1)
                }
                else 
                { console.log(error); cb(-1); }
            });

        }, function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
            cb(-1)
        });
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        console.log(e.code);
        console.log(e.msg);
        cb(-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you make time format like this: `start_time: "0:07:00",` and maybe set `duration_time: 1,` (changed from 2)?

Comment: @VC.One no ,it does not work.

Comment: Try `frame_rate: 30,` with a `start_time: 420,` that should be a random 7 minutes into video (`60 secs x 7 = 420`)... Anyways if all that also fails maybe the system is broken

Comment: It does not work.what do you mean by the system is broken?

Comment: I meant try an alternative method if this one is not working well. One method is to just use video tag + canvas to snapshot the video frame & save an image file.

Answer (score -1):

`start_time` does not work as it has bug in one of its core files. You can resolve the problem using the `hs-node-ffmpeg` package to resolve it.

Comment: Please, add more details. Code example or may be link to the package mentioned to make your answer more useful.